# Changing images with Dark/Light Theme Mode Custom Selector

Tags: javascript, css, image, darkmode

I am trying to change a png image with the filter: invert(100%) property in css using a Javascript selector i've implemented into my site. However, I just can't get my Javascript to change the images. If I manually replace the img class with dark-img, it works - so I know the css does successfully invert the png...there must be an issue in my javascript. Thanks for the help.

HTML

`<img src="assets/img/willpower_logo.png" alt="" class="about__img">`

CSS

```
/*========== Variables Dark theme ==========*/
body.dark-theme{
  /*--HSL Color Mode*/
  --first-color-second: hsl(var(--hue-color), 30%, 8%);
  --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 95%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 75%);
  --input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 29%, 16%);
  --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 28%, 12%);
  --container-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 29%, 16%);
  --scroll-bar-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 12%, 48%);
  --scroll-thumb-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 12%, 36%);
}

img.about__img.dark-img{
  filter: invert(100%);
}

/*========== Button Dark/Light ==========*/
.nav__btns{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.change-theme{
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--title-color);
  margin-right: var(--mb-1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change-theme:hover{
  color: var(--first-color);
}
```

JS

```
const themeButton = document.getElementById('theme-button')
const darkTheme = 'dark-theme'
const iconTheme = 'uil-sun'

// Previously selected topic (if user selected)
const selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selected-theme')
const selectedIcon = localStorage.getItem('selected-icon')

// We obtain the current theme that the interface has by validating the dark-theme class
const getCurrentTheme = () => document.body.classList.contains(darkTheme) ? 'dark' : 'light'
const getCurrentIcon = () => themeButton.classList.contains(iconTheme) ? 'uil-moon' : 'uil-sun'

// We validate if the user previously chose a topic
if (selectedTheme) {
  // If the validation is fulfilled, ask if we activated or deactivated the dark theme
  document.body.classList[selectedTheme === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove'](darkTheme)
  themeButton.classList[selectedIcon === 'uil-moon' ? 'add' : 'remove'](iconTheme)
}

// Activate / deactivate the theme manually with the button
themeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Add or remove the dark / icon theme
    document.body.classList.toggle(darkTheme)
    themeButton.classList.toggle(iconTheme)
    // We save the theme and the current icon that the user chose
    localStorage.setItem('selected-theme', getCurrentTheme())
    localStorage.setItem('selected-icon', getCurrentIcon())
})
```

I tried to add code to the dark/light theme JS to set the images - but doing this just breaks it and makes it unusable.

The dark mode toggle Javascript works very well on body & icon, but I want to also toggle an image.

```
/*==================== DARK LIGHT THEME ====================*/ 
const themeButton = document.getElementById('theme-button')
const darkTheme = 'dark-theme'
const iconTheme = 'uil-sun'
const imgTheme = 'dark-img'

// Previously selected topic (if user selected)
const selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selected-theme')
const selectedIcon = localStorage.getItem('selected-icon')
const selectedImg = localStorage.getItem('selected-img')

// We obtain the current theme that the interface has by validating the dark-theme class
const getCurrentTheme = () => document.body.classList.contains(darkTheme) ? 'dark' : 'light'
const getCurrentIcon = () => themeButton.classList.contains(iconTheme) ? 'uil-moon' : 'uil-sun'
const getCurrentImg = () => document.img.classList.contains(dark-img) ? 'dark' : 'light'

// We validate if the user previously chose a topic
if (selectedTheme) {
  // If the validation is fulfilled, ask if we activated or deactivated the dark theme
  document.body.classList[selectedTheme === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove'](darkTheme)
  themeButton.classList[selectedIcon === 'uil-moon' ? 'add' : 'remove'](iconTheme)
  document.img.about__img.classList[selectedImg === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove'](imgTheme)

// Activate / deactivate the theme manually with the button
themeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Add or remove the dark / icon theme
    document.body.classList.toggle(darkTheme)
    themeButton.classList.toggle(iconTheme)
    document.img.classList.contains(dark-img)
    // We save the theme and the current icon that the user chose
    localStorage.setItem('selected-theme', getCurrentTheme())
    localStorage.setItem('selected-icon', getCurrentIcon())
    localStorage.setItem('sected-img', getCurrentImg())
})
```

Comment: @Yogi Thank you - I was referencing it completely wrong. That worked immediately.